# How to create a layout which has circles and inside the circles are hidden numbers once clicked you view the number. See Image

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How can i create a layout which has circles and inside the circles are hidden numbers once clicked you view the number?. I would like this kind of layout where i have numbers displayed for seconds and hidden by such shapes but i dont know how to achieve this. I am still [image]new in the Android Studio and any help at this moment will be helpful.

This is what i would want it to look like. I want to display on 5 circle/oval buttons with numbers hidden inside and after clicking them that is when you see the numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

circle.xml
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >
    <gradient android:startColor="#FFFF0000" android:endColor="#80FF00FF"
        android:angle="270"/>
</shape>`
using a view with bacackground as circle.xml create a circle
`<View android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circle"/>`
Then onclick hide this layout.show a textview at the position of this layout.

[image]

Comment: on my android studio shape can not be resolved. can you post a picture of the outcome? and is the code complete? what layout are you using? is shape a layout? maybe since im learning from this try putting the entire thing and the layout. Thanks.

Comment: you have to create a xml in drawable which contains the shape code

Comment: Hey thank you very much. :) I have managed finally. Appreciated.